# What does A2034 error "must be in segment block" error mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to create a MASM x86 assembly program. I have created the following files:

NewProcs.inc

```
.NOLIST
;OPTION CASEMAP:NONE        
NewProc PROTO
```

NewProcs.asm

```
INCLUDE NewProcs.inc    
NewProc PROC
; no commands here just for testing purposes
NewProc ENDP
```

I have also set the properties of the project to include the folder where the .inc and .asm file reside. I am calling NewProc from my main proc

I am getting two errors:

- A2034 Must be in segment block: NewProc
- A1010 Unmatched block nesting: NewProc

I have

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
```

in my main procedure, so I tried adding that to the inc file, but that did not help.

I am very new to assembly language and neither of these errors make sense to me (especially the second one)

Any thoughts on what I need to resolve these issues?

Comment: Add a `.code` directive before your `proc`.

Answer (score 1):

@Jester suggested adding .code, and that got me going in the right direction. The full solution is as follows:

- I first removed all of the directories added to the properties of the project. They were not needed.
- I added the .inc and .asm files to the project as existing files
- I changed the .inc and .asm files as follows. The major changes was adding the .code and STDCALL because I was using that as part of the .model

NewProcs.inc

```
NewProc PROTO STDCALL
```

NewProcs.asm

```
INCLUDE NewProcs.inc    

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

.code
NewProcs PROC STDCALL


ret
NewProcs ENDP

END
```